# Process a trivial text sequence using R to extract the required output n x 1 dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string, text, lapply

**Using R:**

How do we process the following input to extract the expected output?

```
Input <- "[Fossil].[Product].Filter(#.Name in {[AB],[AB & BC],[AB-BC],[AB_zz]})"
```

**Expected Output: (data.frame nx1)**

```
AB
AB & BC
AB-BC
AB_zz
```

Comment: Please explain the rules to extract the required text.

Comment: Whatever comes within the ( { [ ] } ) i.e. have a look at the output and compare it with the text. You will understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sub` here followed by a find all:

```r
input <- "[Fossil].[Product].Filter(#.Name in {[AB],[AB & BC],[AB-BC],[AB_zz]})"
terms <- sub("^.*\\{(.*?)\\}.*$", "\\1", input)
output <- regmatches(terms, gregexpr("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])", terms, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
output

[1] "AB"      "AB & BC" "AB-BC"   "AB_zz"
```

We first use `sub` to isolate the term in brackets `{...}`.  Then, we do a regex find all for all terms inside square brackets, to generate the output you want.

Comment: How do we remove the brackets [ ] in the begging and the end and store them in n x 1 data frame? Just like I mentioned in the "Expected Output" section on the description.

Comment: Use: `your_df <- data.frame(nx1=output, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: What I am expecting is AB  AB & BC AB-BC  AB_zz and what I have from your solution is  "[AB]"      "[AB & BC]" "[AB-BC]"   "[AB_zz]"

Comment: n x 1 means row x columns of a data frame and not the name of the df that I want. Sorry, if I didn't sound clear.

Comment: Please edit your sample data to reveal the real problem.  I have answered to the data actually given.

Comment: My sample data is on point! Your answer outputs the required text with [ ] which is to be eliminated. Could you remove the [ ] from your end result and just provide me with the text inside?

Comment: Such a boss. Thank you so much. Do you have any links or references from where I can learn Regex?

Comment: One great site: www.rexegg.com